# Respond to custom URL in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

So, I'm trying to write a wordpress plugin which acts like an API and responds to a specific HTTP request. I cache some data in my plugin and I would like to fetch the data in the other side using AJAX or sth.
What actions or filters should I use? I've tried using **request** filter but couldn't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the WP REST API for this: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Below is a simple example of how to add a custom route and how to handle the request.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/my-custom-route/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );


function my_awesome_func( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  // You can access parameters via direct array access on the object:
  $param = $request['some_param'];

  // Or via the helper method:
  $param = $request->get_param( 'some_param' );

  // You can get the combined, merged set of parameters:
  $parameters = $request->get_params();

  // The individual sets of parameters are also available, if needed:
  $parameters = $request->get_url_params();
  $parameters = $request->get_query_params();
  $parameters = $request->get_body_params();
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  $parameters = $request->get_default_params();

  // Uploads aren't merged in, but can be accessed separately:
  $parameters = $request->get_file_params();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find this simple answer anywhere. And we can as well return a custom content to the client, am I right?

Comment: Yes you can `return [some_data]` in the custom route callback.